# CIFS mounts broken after update from 23.04 to 23.10

Tags: mount, cifs, 23.10

For some weird reason my CIFS mounts have failed following the recent upgrade from ubuntu 23.04 to 23.10

Here's my `/etc/fstab` file...

```
//192.168.0.6/Backup   /media/backup         cifs   rw,credentials=/home/grego/credentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,vers=3.0,noauto,x-systemd.automount,user   0 0 

//192.168.0.6/Shared   /media/shared         cifs   rw,credentials=/home/grego/credentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,vers=3.0,noauto,x-systemd.automount,user   0 0 

//192.168.0.6/Media    /media/media          cifs   rw,credentials=/home/grego/credentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,vers=2.1,noauto,x-systemd.automount,user   0 0
```

Here are the `dmesg` entries...

```
[   45.896237] CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.0.6/Backup
[   45.905758] CIFS: VFS: \\192.168.0.6 failed to connect to IPC (rc=-13)
[   46.939466] CIFS: VFS: session 0000000065a0c2f2 has no tcon available for a dfs referral request
[   47.980397] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13

[   94.177796] CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.0.6/Media
[   94.187246] CIFS: VFS: \\192.168.0.6 failed to connect to IPC (rc=-13)
[   95.192181] CIFS: VFS: session 00000000a9bfc9f5 has no tcon available for a dfs referral request
[   96.216339] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13

[  106.651636] CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.0.6/Shared
[  106.661132] CIFS: VFS: \\192.168.0.6 failed to connect to IPC (rc=-13)
[  107.675401] CIFS: VFS: session 0000000061820eef has no tcon available for a dfs referral request
[  108.695527] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

Here's the `systemctl status NetworkManager-wait-online.service` output...

```
● NetworkManager-wait-online.service - Network Manager Wait Online
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager-wait-online.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2023-11-05 17:43:29 AEDT; 5min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager-wait-online.service(8)
    Process: 1011 ExecStart=/usr/bin/nm-online -s -q (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1011 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 11ms
```

When I do a `sudo mount -a` here's what I get...

```
mount: Partition: mount point does not exist.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

I want to be clear. No changes were made, except the upgrade to 23.10. Is there anything else that could help?

Comment: have you checked to see if the mount points you created in 23.04 still exist?

Comment: Turns out the only way to sort it out, was to remove the drive mappings from the /etc/fstab file. And then in Dolphin I used the Add Network Folder. This is weird because I have always been able to use the fstab file.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue as well in Ubuntu 23.10 for Arm.  I get the same -13 access denied error as you.

My fstab entries do not differ from yours in any meaningful way.  I copied my entries from a working 22.04 workstation and tried replicate the mounts to a new 23.04 pi.

All the mounts failed.

I did a Wireshark trace and found that it is not passing the credentials from the the file specified in fstab. The username was blank.

I changed the credential file name to one that does not exist and neither mount nor mount.cifs complained.

I did an strace on a mount command and it did not try to open the credentials file.

From all appearances there is an issue with the credentials switch in 23.04.

UPDATE:

This fixes it:

sudo apt install cifs-utils